# tsconfig.json include property

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig

I am looking at tsconfig.json `include` property. In official documentation it says `'Specifies an array of filenames or patterns to include in the program.'` And when angular application is created it auto generats this property

```
"include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
```

But as I see in angular application, the application also works fine when this property is removed. So my question is why do we need to include any files using this property, what are we missing if we don't do it?

Answer (score 0):

Its empty by default so I guess its only there for the `files`.

[image: image of include]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The include property specifies the files to be included in the TypeScript project. You can either include files or file paths like ./src/** to specify what should be included.